# Servlet can't find the file specified

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Please help me. I'm new to java, especially java web (JSP).

So in my case when I try to login, the servlet class will call my configuration class first that configures the log4j configuration file.

Here is my project tree:

[image]

and here's my code :

1. Login Servlet

   ```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
       throws ServletException, IOException{  

       System.out.println("Before Starting...");
       MainConfiguration.loadConfiguration();

       response.setContentType("text/html");
       RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");  
       rd.forward(request, response);
   }
   ```
2. MainConfiguration

   ```
   public static void loadConfiguration()
   {
       // To configure place of logger settings file
       PropertyConfigurator.configure("configuration/logger_dev.conf");
   }
   ```

so when i'm trying to run the project and try to login, it throws an error.

```
Before Starting...
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [configuration/logger_dev.conf].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: configuration\logger_dev.conf (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:297)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:315)
    at com.utility.MainConfiguration.loadConfiguration(MainConfiguration.java:47)
    at com.controller.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:20)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [configuration/logger_dev.conf].
```

But when I'm trying to call my configuration class using java main, it works fine.

Please suggest on how to get it to work on the servlet. thanks.

Comment: Your files are trying to be loaded from the WebContent folder, probably

Comment: @cricket_007 i've tried to copy my configuration folder inside the WebContent folder, but still not working.

Comment: You need to place the file on the classpath.Try placing it in a folder that is on the classpath like the source folder, click project properties and see what folders in class path and choose one to put the configuration on.

Comment: Except src folder is never on the classpath of built Eclipse projects (especially web ones), so there's that

Comment: Also, the image says the file is at `configuration/db/logger_dev.conf`, not `configuration/logger_dev.conf`

Comment: @user7790438 i've tried to add my configuration folder into classpath like the src folder, but still got error :(

Comment: @JimGarrison nope, the db folder is not expand so its in configuration not configuration/db

Answer (score 0):

Resources like configuration files can be read from

1. The file system. This is not recommended because the file will typically not be part of the deployed WAR and must therefore be handled separately (and when it is you don't know where it ends up on the file system after deployment).
2. The classpath. Make sure the build process copies the file into the deployed classpath (same directory where the `.class` files end up). The file can then be accessed via `java.lang.Class.getResource` or `java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream`.
3. The WEB content, e.g. somewhere in the `WEB-INF` folder to avoid that the file is delivered to clients. It can then be accessed via `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResource` or `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResourceAsStream`.